# Google app script not getting doPost() request from Announcement Page

Tags: google-apps-script

I have to pass data of an announcement from App script to my spreadsheet using Google App script. I have created an announcement page and I have an app script attached to the Announcement page which is a simple `doPost()`. It looks like this:

```
function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

For the same page; `doGet()` returns a response. However, `doPost()` returns nothing. I am unable to understand that I am able to see the data of post request when I open up my developer's console but not in the parameter of `doPost()`. I have also logged this an [Announcement page issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6257). If someone can guide through this I would be very grateful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wont work like this. We need to use Google's Announcement class to get the list of contents from announcements page. For more reference, please refer to this link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/page